# BaseExpandableListAdapter add child programmatically

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to programmatically add a child to the parent. That just did not try, nothing works.

My code:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private List<String> _listDataHeader; 
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
```

........

```
     public void addChild(int groupPosition, String name){
        List<String> childs = _listDataChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition));
        childs.add(name);
        _listDataChild.put(_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition), childs);

        notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
```

And

```
groupPosition = 0
addChild(groupPosition, "lalala");
```

return Error;

```
11-08 15:33:06.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 15:33:06.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27857): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
11-08 15:33:06.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27857):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
11-08 15:33:06.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27857):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
11-08 15:33:06.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27857):    at com.example.pagereader.ExpandableListAdapter.getChildView(ExpandableListAdapter.java:95)
11-08 15:33:06.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27857):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:450)
11-08 15:33:06.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27857):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2088)
...
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here It is..

I've class name **SortCategoryExpand**

in which i've initialize  **ExpandableListAdapter**

```
expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext());

            expListAdapter.setupTrips(aryAbsence,aryTicket,aryTimeSheet); // Mathod in ExpandableListAdapter class and data in aryLists.

            expList.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

            if (expListAdapter.getChildrenCount(0) >= 1) {
                expList.expandGroup(0);
            }
```

Now here it is **ExpandableListAdapter** class

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
/*
 * view types
 */
SortCategoryExpand sortCategoryExpand = new SortCategoryExpand();

private static final int VIEW_1 = 0;
private static final int View_2 = 1;
private static final int View_3=2;

/*
 * data
 */
private Context context = null;
ArrayList<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    int type = -1;

    if (groupPosition == 2) {
        type = View_3;
    }
    else if (groupPosition == 1) {
        type = View_2;
    }else  {
        type = View_1;
    }

    return type;
}

@Override
public int getChildTypeCount() {
    // Past and Future Travel Plans
    return 3;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition).entryItems.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // get the type of the group this child belongs
    Type viewType = groups.get(groupPosition).type;
    View view = convertView;

    if (viewType == Type.Data1) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.category_absence_line_item, parent, false);

            Data1ViewHolder holder = new Data1ViewHolder ();
            holder.txtSubject = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            holder.txtFromUser = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user);
            holder.txtStartDate = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.startDate);
            holder.txtEndDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.endDate);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        Data1ViewHolder holder = (Data1ViewHolder ) view.getTag();

        EntryItem entryItem = (EntryItem) getChild(groupPosition,
                childPosition);

        if (entryItem.subject.equals("None")) {
            holder.txtSubject.setText("None");
        } else {

            holder.txtSubject.setText("" + entryItem.subject);
        }
        if (entryItem.fromUser.equals("None")) {
            holder.txtFromUser.setText("");
        } else if (entryItem.fromUser.equals("anyType{}")) {
            holder.txtFromUser.setText("From User : ");
        } else {
            holder.txtFromUser.setText("From User : " + entryItem.fromUser);
        }
        if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(entryItem.startDate)
                .equals("01-Jan-1970")) {
            holder.txtStartDate.setText("Start Date : None");
        } else if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(
                entryItem.startDate).equals("03-Mar-3800")) {
            holder.txtStartDate.setText("");
        } else {
            holder.txtStartDate.setText("Start Date : "
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                            .format(entryItem.startDate));
        }

        if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(entryItem.endDate)
                .equals("01-Jan-1970")) {
            holder.txtEndDate.setText("Due Date : None");
        } else if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(
                entryItem.endDate).equals("03-Mar-3800")) {
            holder.txtStartDate.setText("");
        } else {
            holder.txtEndDate.setText("Due Date : "
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                            .format(entryItem.endDate));
        }
    }else ifviewType == Type.Data2){

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.category_ticket_line_item, parent, false);

            Data2ViewHolder holder = new Data2ViewHolder ();
            holder.txtSubject = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            holder.txtFromUser = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user);
            holder.txtStartDate = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.startDate);
            holder.txtEndDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.endDate);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        Data2ViewHolder holder = (Data2ViewHolder ) view.getTag();

        EntryItem entryItem = (EntryItem) getChild(groupPosition,
                childPosition);

        if (entryItem.subject.equals("None")) {
            holder.txtSubject.setText("None");
        } else {

            holder.txtSubject.setText("" + entryItem.subject);
        }
        if (entryItem.fromUser.equals("None")) {
            holder.txtFromUser.setText("");
        } else if (entryItem.fromUser.equals("anyType{}")) {
            holder.txtFromUser.setText("From User : ");
        } else {
            holder.txtFromUser.setText("From User : " + entryItem.fromUser);
        }
        if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(entryItem.startDate)
                .equals("01-Jan-1970")) {
            holder.txtStartDate.setText("Start Date : None");
        } else if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(
                entryItem.startDate).equals("03-Mar-3800")) {
            holder.txtStartDate.setText("");
        } else {
            holder.txtStartDate.setText("Start Date : "
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                            .format(entryItem.startDate));
        }

        if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(entryItem.endDate)
                .equals("01-Jan-1970")) {
            holder.txtEndDate.setText("Due Date : None");
        } else if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(
                entryItem.endDate).equals("03-Mar-3800")) {
            holder.txtStartDate.setText("");
        } else {
            holder.txtEndDate.setText("Due Date : "
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                            .format(entryItem.endDate));
        }

    }
    else if(viewType == Type.Data3){

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.category_timesheet_line_item, parent, false);

            Data3ViewHolder holder = new Data3ViewHolder ();
            holder.txtSubject = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            holder.txtFromUser = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user);
            holder.txtStartDate = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.startDate);
            holder.txtEndDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.endDate);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        Data3ViewHolder holder = (Data3ViewHolder ) view.getTag();

        EntryItem entryItem = (EntryItem) getChild(groupPosition,
                childPosition);

        if (entryItem.subject.equals("None")) {
            holder.txtSubject.setText("None");
        } else {

            holder.txtSubject.setText("" + entryItem.subject);
        }
        if (entryItem.fromUser.equals("None")) {
            holder.txtFromUser.setText("");
        } else if (entryItem.fromUser.equals("anyType{}")) {
            holder.txtFromUser.setText("From User : ");
        } else {
            holder.txtFromUser.setText("From User : " + entryItem.fromUser);
        }
        if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(entryItem.startDate)
                .equals("01-Jan-1970")) {
            holder.txtStartDate.setText("Start Date : None");
        } else if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(
                entryItem.startDate).equals("03-Mar-3800")) {
            holder.txtStartDate.setText("");
        } else {
            holder.txtStartDate.setText("Start Date : "
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                            .format(entryItem.startDate));
        }

        if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(entryItem.endDate)
                .equals("01-Jan-1970")) {
            holder.txtEndDate.setText("Due Date : None");
        } else if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(
                entryItem.endDate).equals("03-Mar-3800")) {
            holder.txtStartDate.setText("");
        } else {
            holder.txtEndDate.setText("Due Date : "
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                            .format(entryItem.endDate));
        }

    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition).entryItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Type viewType = groups.get(groupPosition).type;
    View view = convertView;

    if (viewType == Type.Data1) {
        view = null;
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.expandable_list_group_absenceview, parent,
                    false);

            Data1ViewHolder holder = new Data1ViewHolder ();
            holder.textabsence = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.AbsencegroupHeader);
            holder.imageAbsence = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.AbsenceexpandableIcon);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        Data1ViewHolder holder = (Data1ViewHolder ) view.getTag();

        holder.textabsence.setText("Human Resource Absence" + " " + "("
                + groups.get(groupPosition).entryItems.size() + ")");

        if (groups.get(groupPosition).entryItems.size() == 0) {
            holder.imageAbsence.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            int imageResourceId = isExpanded ? android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float
                    : android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float;
            holder.imageAbsence.setImageResource(imageResourceId);

            holder.imageAbsence.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }else if(viewType == Type.Data2) {
        view = null;
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.expandable_list_group_ticketview, parent,
                    false);

            Data2ViewHolder holder = new Data2ViewHolder ();
            holder.textticket = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.TicketgroupHeader);
            holder.imageTicket= (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.TicketexpandableIcon);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        Data2ViewHolder holder = (Data2ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        holder.textticket.setText("Ticket Approvals" + " " + "("
                + groups.get(groupPosition).entryItems.size() + ")");

        if (groups.get(groupPosition).entryItems.size() == 0) {
            holder.imageTicket.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            int imageResourceId = isExpanded ? android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float
                    : android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float;
            holder.imageTicket.setImageResource(imageResourceId);

            holder.imageTicket.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    else if(viewType == Type.Data3) {
        view = null;
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.expandable_list_group_timesheetview, parent,
                    false);

            Data3ViewHolder holder = new Data3ViewHolder ();
            holder.texttimesheet = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.TimesheetgroupHeader);
            holder.imageTimesheet= (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.TimesheetexpandableIcon);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        Data3ViewHolder holder = (Data3ViewHolder ) view.getTag();

        holder.texttimesheet.setText("TimeSheet Approvals" + " " + "("
                + groups.get(groupPosition).entryItems.size() + ")");

        if (groups.get(groupPosition).entryItems.size() == 0) {
            holder.imageTimesheet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            int imageResourceId = isExpanded ? android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float
                    : android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float;
            holder.imageTimesheet.setImageResource(imageResourceId);

            holder.imageTimesheet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public void setupTrips(ArrayList<EntryItem> aryAbsence,ArrayList<EntryItem> aryTicket, ArrayList<EntryItem> aryTimeSheet) {
    groups.clear();

    if (aryAbsence != null) {
        Group g1 = new Group();
        g1.type = Type.Absence;
        g1.entryItems.clear();
        g1.entryItems = new ArrayList<EntryItem>(aryAbsence);

        groups.add(g1);
    }
    if (aryTicket != null) {
        Group g2 = new Group();
        g2.type = Type.Ticket;
        g2.entryItems.clear();
        g2.entryItems = new ArrayList<EntryItem>(aryTicket);

        groups.add(g2);
    }
    if (aryTimeSheet != null) {
        Group g3 = new Group();
        g3.type = Type.TimeSheet;
        g3.entryItems.clear();
        g3.entryItems = new ArrayList<EntryItem>(aryTimeSheet);

        groups.add(g3);
    }


    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/*
 * Holder for the Past view type
 */

public static class Data1ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageAbsence;
    public TextView textabsence;
    public TextView txtEndDate;
    public TextView txtStartDate;
    public TextView txtFromUser;
    public TextView txtSubject;

}

public static class Data2ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageTicket;
    public TextView textticket;
    public TextView txtEndDate;
    public TextView txtStartDate;
    public TextView txtFromUser;
    public TextView txtSubject;

}
public static class Data3ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageTimesheet;
    public TextView texttimesheet;
    public TextView txtEndDate;
    public TextView txtStartDate;
    public TextView txtFromUser;
    public TextView txtSubject;

}

/*
 * Wrapper for each group that contains the list elements and the type of
 * travel.
 */
public static class Group {
    public enum Type {
        Data_1,Data_2,Data_3;
    };

    public Type type;
    ArrayList<EntryItem> entryItems = new ArrayList<EntryItem>();
}

}
```

Here EntryItem is Bean class where I've use getter setter method. And other you have to make some xml files for Holder. If any Query you can ask here I've huge data so code may be little complex but you can use it for globally.

Comment: How does your getChildView work for you? The child position is inconsistent for me. So, if I track the view in the child and give it an ID, I can see that I sometimes get a different child position for the view with the same ID. It really affects the data in my child view.